# Calling a function that returns its updated output python

Tags: python, pandas, np

So I'm completely having a brain fart but I'm attempting to call a function that returns its own updated input in a for loop that has to run 30 times.
I have the for loop part down I'm just not sure how to call the function correctly.

```
def miniopoloy_turn(state, cash)
    return state, cash
```

so the function returns its updated state and cash values after running, but how would I then run the function again with the updated output inside a for loop?

Comment: It's spelled `cache`...

Comment: I mean in this case its actually referring to money, like cash...

Comment: Haha, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to simply store the returned values in local variables and re-run the function as many times as necessary:

```
# 1. set up initial values
state = ...
cash = ...
# 2. run the function iteratively
for i in xrange(30):
    state, cash = miniopoly_turn(state, cash)
    print state, cash
# 3. profit!
```

Comment: So in this case state and cash will be updated with each iteration of the loop and the function will run with the updated values? Man I had this exact code and overthought it and didn't think it would work like this... Thanks!

Comment: @andrewfay Exactly. The alternative is to use global variables.